# ActiveRecord find_by generateing select statement that does not work with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jwt

I'm using the Knock gem for JWT authentication in my rails api application. When I create a user with a password everything is fine but then when I hit the route that generates the user_token, I get a 500 error. Knock Gem does an Activerecord find_by on the model being referenced

```
(this is from https://github.com/nsarno/knock/blob/master/app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb)
entity_class.find_by email: auth_params[:email]
```

which triggers this select statement.

```
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@testuser.ca"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Unfortunately, the return is a 500

I put the select statement into Postico and ran it manually and it still fails. That is when I discovered that Postgres does not like ( support?) double quotes around values. When I changed the email value to single quotes for the email it worked

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'no-reply@testuser.ca' LIMIT 1 ;
```

Double quotes around the column names seems to be fine.

The tricky thing is that this only happens in my production environment that I have set up via a digital ocean droplet. I have Capistrano set up to deploy my application. Locally, the user creation and user_token works perfectly. I'm not sure why it would work locally when running code, but when I hit my local database with Postico and try the same statement, it crashes as well.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this or why this is happening would be much appreciated.

---

Log file when it happens

```ruby
[1cbc2966-b7e9-4630-a7e9-07ba13818f2d] puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
I, [2018-07-30T19:56:43.531575 #29634]  INFO -- : [a11ba95e-d286-4405-8058-7a8594ba07e1] Started GET "/" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2018-07-30 19:56:43 +0000
I, [2018-07-30T19:56:43.532229 #29634]  INFO -- : [a11ba95e-d286-4405-8058-7a8594ba07e1] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
I, [2018-07-30T19:56:43.533500 #29634]  INFO -- : [a11ba95e-d286-4405-8058-7a8594ba07e1] [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.07ms)
I, [2018-07-30T19:56:43.533660 #29634]  INFO -- : [a11ba95e-d286-4405-8058-7a8594ba07e1] Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms)
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.491431 #29634]  INFO -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8] Started POST "/users/create" for 184.69.39.226 at 2018-07-30 20:03:11 +0000
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.492263 #29634]  INFO -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8] Processing by UsersController#create as */*
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.492443 #29634]  INFO -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8]   Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.ca", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
D, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.582384 #29634] DEBUG -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8]    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.583996 #29634] DEBUG -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8]   User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@test.ca"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.585818 #29634] DEBUG -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8]   User Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@test.ca"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$qyZRU.Sxn9mbPI/AQPMnquyiVFKhX8aG8ClPlYdhxivkPQ5XmX0UO"], ["created_at", "2018-07-30 20:03:11.584946"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-30 20:03:11.584946"]]
D, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.586807 #29634] DEBUG -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8]    (0.6ms)  COMMIT
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.588042 #29634]  INFO -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8] [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.07ms)
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:11.588329 #29634]  INFO -- : [fccff2d7-6398-4ff0-883d-26cc1c02d9f8] Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.588367 #29634]  INFO -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] Started POST "/user_token" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2018-07-30 20:03:15 +0000
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.589280 #29634]  INFO -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] Processing by UserTokenController#create as */*
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.589487 #29634]  INFO -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4]   Parameters: {"auth"=>{"email"=>"test@test.ca", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "user_token"=>{"auth"=>{"email"=>"test@test.ca", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
D, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.591732 #29634] DEBUG -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4]   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@test.ca"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
I, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.667905 #29634]  INFO -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 78ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
F, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.669634 #29634] FATAL -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4]
F, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.669803 #29634] FATAL -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
F, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.669896 #29634] FATAL -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4]
F, [2018-07-30T20:03:15.669994 #29634] FATAL -- : [24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:75:in `digest'
[24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:75:in `sign_hmac'
[24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:36:in `sign'
[24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:96:in `encoded_signature'
[24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:106:in `encode'
[24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] knock (2.1.1) app/model/knock/auth_token.rb:14:in `initialize'
[24372279-3ea9-4f24-b10f-ccd463c3c8b4] knock (2.1.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:22:in `new'
```

---

Further investigation

I turned my local environment into "production" mode and created the production database locally. I experience the same 500 internal server error that I do when hitting my VPS that's also in Production mode! This seems to be a difference between development and production of Active Record and how it works with PostgreSQL?

Still trying to figure this out, if anyone has any experience with this please let me know :)

Comment: Do you use postgres locally too?

Comment: Ya, I try and keep my local and production environment as close as possible.

Comment: So I turned my local environment into "production" mode and created the production database. I experience the same issues that I do when hitting my VPS thats also in Production mode!  This seems to be a difference between developer and production and how it works with postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The query is fine, and unrelated to your problem.

Your log output shows an error that has nothing to do with Postgres:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:75:in `digest'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:75:in `sign_hmac'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:36:in `sign'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:96:in `encoded_signature'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:106:in `encode'
knock (2.1.1) app/model/knock/auth_token.rb:14:in `initialize'
knock (2.1.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:22:in `new'
```

Comment: I'm assuming that because the query had double quotes for the value, its returns nil instead of the actual row. Or would the error be different if the query ran incorrectly?

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to have stemmed from Rails no longer using secrets but credentials in 5.2

Here is the github issue for Knock
https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/205